# Php tmpfile only works from command line

Tags: php, temporary-files, spl

When I run this:

```
$file = tmpfile();
$name = stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'];
$nfile = new SplFileObject($name);
var_dump($nfile);
```

from the command line, it works as expected - creating a temporary file, and dumping details about it. However, when I run it through apache, $nfile is an empty object - it seems to be unable to access the file by path. Why is this? I have already confirmed that it is creating a file, and I can see the temporary file in the file system, so it's just php that can't reach it.

Comment: ususally php-cli and php-fpm or apaches' may use different php.inis with different default settings, might want to check there for security stuff like `open_basedir` disabled functions `stream_get_meta_data` and such. Also try `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1)` to get some feedback

Comment: You might not have enough permissions to write that tmpfile. When you run from the command line you are using the current logged-in user, however when you run from apache the user that run's your code is apache's user and permissions. You might wanna check http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php, to see which folder you are trying to write your tmpfile to and make sure that you have enough permissions to write to that folder.